# Why isn't my image aligning to the bottom of my grid column?

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-grid

I'm trying to setup a grid system with one side a form and the other one an image. Now the problem is that I want everything to go to the bottom of the viewport, but for some reason the image doesn't go to the bottom of the screen.

I've already tried putting a `height: 100vh` on `body, *` and the image itself but it didn't change.

```css
.login-section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: "form form form form form form form form map map map map";
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

.login-section .login-form {
  grid-area: form;
}

.login-section .login-map {
  grid-area: map;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-section">
  <div class="login-map">
    <img src="../img/map.png" alt="photo map">
  </div>
  <div class="login-form">
    <div class="login-form-back">
      Bla bla login
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `height: 100vh` for `login-section` and use `align-items: flex-end` - see demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0; /* Reset body-margin */
}
img {
  display: block; /* Remove whitespace below image*/
  height: 100%; /* Image extending the full height of the grid item */
}

.login-section {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas: "form form form form form form form form map map map map";
    /*align-items: center;*/
    align-items: flex-end; /* ADDED */
    height: 100vh; /* ADDED */
    justify-items: center;
}

.login-section .login-form {
    grid-area: form;
}

.login-section .login-map {
    grid-area: map;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100vh; /* image over full viewport*/
}
```

```html
<div class="login-section">
        <div class="login-map">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="photo map">
        </div>
        <div class="login-form">
            <div class="login-form-back">
                Bla bla login
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's just pushing down everything, there is a scroll now and a white space above the image

Comment: @TristanVermeesch check out the edited answer and let me know if it looks fine now...

Comment: Tha still don't work, it's going outside of it's grid if resizing now

Comment: So the image should extend from the top to the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Yes, it should take the full height

Comment: @TristanVermeesch add `height: 100vh` to the `login-map` and `height: 100%` to the `img` - see updated answer..